# How to insert an icon that has an embedded link, which opens in a new tab

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to have a github icon with a link that when pressed will open the link. This is what I have so far, I have the icon but when I click on it, the link doesn't open.

[image]

This is my latex

```
\cvsection{Projects}
\item {\textbf{Resilient Classroom}
\extrainfo{\faGithub\href{https://github.com/Adib234/resilient_classroom}

\begin {itemize}
\item A \textbf{Flutter} app with \textbf{Firebase} that's a \textbf{Google Classroom clone} for kids with dyslexia 
\end {itemize}
\item {\textbf{Google CSSI-Coursera}} \extrainfo{\faGithub\href{https://github.com/Adib234/algorithms-on-graphs}


\begin {itemize}
\item Implemented \textbf{8+ graph algorithms} such as path-finding and social networks in \textbf{Python} demonstrating \textbf{data structure and algorithm proficiency}.
\end {itemize}
```

Comment: `\href` need two arguments, i.e.,  `\href{URL}{DESCRIPTION}`

Comment: Thank you, my question has been solved now

Comment: Unrelated, but in your (incomplete) MWE there are some closing braces missing ...

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

A solution is

```
\href{your URL}{\faGithub}
```

or also

```
\hyperref[your URL]{\faGithub}
```

or also

```
\hyperlink{your URL}{\faGithub}
```

where your URL is taken from the GitHub page of your project

- Code button (in green)
- Copy button for the HTTPS, SSH or Github CLI

Comment: Should be mentioned in the answer that `\usepackage{hyperref}` is required